# How to assert many facts into knowledge base at once?

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate that asserts many facts into knowledge base to describe a grid for the Wumpus game. Basically, the following method generates arcs to describe all possible player transitions.

```
init_map :- ( cell(X-Y),
              adj(X-Y, X1-Y1),
              assert(arc_from_to(X-Y, X1-Y1)) ).
```

The problem is that it prints `true` after each assertion which is not good since it's important to assert all arcs instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the de facto standard `forall/2` predicate, which implements a generate and test loop?

```
init_map :-
    forall(
        (cell(X-Y), adj(X-Y, X1-Y1)),
        assert(arc_from_to(X-Y, X1-Y1))
    ).
```

That said, why using a dynamic predicate? Why not use instead:

```
arc_from_to(X-Y, X1-Y1) :-
    cell(X-Y),
    adj(X-Y, X1-Y1).
```

Comment: Wow, will it work the same way as a bunch of dynamic ones does?